# Finding pressure inside a container

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

> Pressure $(P_o)$ outside the container is $10^5 \ \ \mathrm{Pa}$. A force of $480 \ \ \mathrm N$ is required to remove the lid. The area of the lid is $50 \ \ \mathrm m^2$. Find the pressure $(P_i)$ inside the container.

[image]

I drew the diagram. It was not given with the question.

From the diagram I equated force,

$F + P_i \times A = A\times P_o$

$\implies F + P_i \times 50 = 50\times P_o$

$\implies 480 + P_i \times 50 = 50\times 10^5$

$\implies P_i \times 5 = 5\times 10^5 - 48 = 499952$

$\implies P_i = 99990.4 \ \ \mathrm {Pa}$

The answer is $4 \ \ \mathrm {kPa}$.

I don't know why I got the pressure this much off, I equated forces acting on the lid of the container properly.

This is a easy question still after trying so much I can't get the answer :((.

Please explain me the problem in my answer.

Comment: Are you certain about the givens and units? I see an error in your math.

Comment: @Inquisitive I think yes because I just kept everything in SI units.

Comment: @Inquisitive The question is from *Principle of physics* by Halliday. Chapter is fluid and question number 15.

Comment: I think the book answer is wrong, but I'm still in disbelief!

Comment: @Inquisitive You can check if you have the book., Please.

Comment: I'm looking at it simply as the sum of the forces equals zero. If we're correct, you have a lousy textbook.

Comment: @Inquisitive I get all the lousy textbooks :))) * _ *

Comment: If I'm wrong, I'll feel like an utter idiot!

Comment: @Inquisitive I can understand, That's why I no longer answer any question on the network.

Comment: What edition of the book did you use? I just checked the 9th edition (of which a complete pdf is online) and question 2 in Chapter 14 talks about an area of 77 m$^2$ (but otherwise it's obviously the same problem). Their "negligible mass" is even more outrageous with those dimensions...

Comment: @Floris 10th edition.

Comment: 10 editions and the error is still there... Amazing. Time for a note to the editors. I assume the original Halliday is no longer making updates to his _Magnum Opus_.

Comment: FYI - I discovered Halliday passed away years ago; I have sent an email to Prof Walker.

Comment: @Floris None of the original authors are alive now. How did you get the mail of Jearl Walker ? I also want to inform him about another error that I spotted in a work-energy problem.

Comment: I googled him. He is at http://facultyprofile.csuohio.edu/csufacultyprofile/detail.cfm?FacultyID=HRW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a typo in the textbook. If you go backwards from the provided answer of $P_i=4\,\mbox{kPa}$, you find that the force should have been $4{,}800\,\mbox{kN}$, instead of $480\,\mbox{N}$ which is a suspiciously small force on such a huge lid. $50\,\mbox{m}^2$ is the size of a small apartment, mind you. In New York city, it would be the size of quite a stately apartment ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the analogy, That made be giggle.

Comment: Are you sure about that 480 kN working out to the correct answer?

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part now. Fixed.

Comment: @Pirx You corrected it to work. Alas, we'll never know the true intent of the textbook.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a simple typo now anymore. Who knows, stuff happens.

Comment: @Pirx I fell bad when a book almost 60 years old has a typo.

Answer (score 2):

It's obvious the book has a typo.

50 square meters is not a "container" - it's a handful of buses...

Let's assume they meant 50 cm$^2$ and see where that gets us.

Then the force on the lid due to the external atmosphere is 500 N, and we need an internal force of 20 N to give a net force of 480 N. That makes the internal pressure 20/500 of the external pressure, or 4 kPa.

Seems a lot more reasonable.